# MongoDB: network error while attempting to run command 'validate'

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

Due to the issue with MongoDB mentioned [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/WT-8395) I have to run `Validate` command and check collections, but command is being executed really long time and as results I'm getting error:

> network error while attempting to run command 'validate'

Mongo shell and server versions are the same. Connection is done by using `TLS`. Validation is executed on the same host where server is running to avoid network issues.
Is there any way to get validation results even if CLI client is disconnected? Or maybe there is a way to avoid this network issue?

Comment: How exactly did you try co connect. Could you check Mongo logs and paste it here?

Comment: connecting via CLI, mongo shell v5.0.4, `mongo --tls --tlsAllowInvalidCertificates <URI>`, actually there are no server errors, this is client side error only or I could miss some logs, but in general log in the name of post

Comment: Please paste the logs into the question. Without them, it's really hard to guess what could have gone wrong.

Comment: Sorry, seems like it's not relevant anymore since we went by path of resync of one node of replicaSet. But of course it would be great option if mongodb saved validation somewhere so it could be accessed anytime.

Comment: So is your problem now resolved?

Comment: Well, I'd rather say that I just avoided using that command and that's all, but I guess main question is how to get validation results even if client disconnected by any reason. Because actually server continues to execute validation and it would be logical to store somewhere results otherwise it does not make any sense

Comment: Please provide yaml files and reproduction steps. Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you deploy your cluster?