# MongoDB CLI info.log custom message

Tags: mongodb

I need to log info on `Secondary` node of `replicaSet`. Since I'm not able to write anything on `Secondary` I'm asking if this is possible to write some custom message directly to the mongodb log?
I need this since I can not retrieve response of my operation as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70306771/mongodb-network-error-while-attempting-to-run-command-validate)
Maybe there is any other possibility to store result of my operation?